# Unexpected exception while running a report in BIRT

Tags: sql, oracle, birt

Below is an SQL query to retrieve specific data from an Oracle database 11g, to populate a BIRT report.

```
  select
P.LAST_NAME,
P.FIRST_NAME,
A.EMPLID,
J.EMPL_RCD_NBR,
E.HIRE_DT,
E.SERVICE_DT,
'XXX-XX-' || substr(P.SSN,6,4) SSN,
P.STREET1,
P.STREET2,
P.CITY,
P.STATE,
P.ZIP,
P.COUNTRY,
P.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
P.BIRTHDATE,
P.ETHNIC_GROUP,
P.RACE_ETHNICITY,
P.SEX,
P.MAR_STATUS,
J.EFFDT,
J.EFFSEQ,
J.ACTION,
J.EMPL_STATUS,
J.COMPANY,
J.PAYGROUP,
J.DEPTID,
J.LOCATION,
J.REPORTING_LOCATION,
J.JOBCODE,
J.JOB_ENTRY_DT,
--J.PRIMARY_JOB,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM PS_PRIMARY_JOB PJ WHERE PJ.EMPLID = J.EMPLID and PJ.EMPL_RCD_NBR =  J.EMPL_RCD_NBR and     PJ.EFFDT =
    coalesce((select max(EFFDT)
              from PS_PRIMARY_JOB
              where EMPLID = PJ.EMPLID
              and EFFDT <= to_date(@SingleQuote.Local.THRUDATE~,'MM/DD/YYYY')),
             (select min(EFFDT)
              from PS_PRIMARY_JOB
              where EMPLID = PJ.EMPLID))) then 'Y' else 'N' end as PRIMARY_JOB,
J.EMPL_TYPE,
J.COMP_FREQUENCY,
J.COMPRATE,
J.RATE_TYPE,
J.RATE_1,
J.STD_HOURS,
J.CURRENCY_CD,
J.REPORTS_TO_ID,
J.FLSA_STATUS,
T.FILE_NBR,
T.FED_ALLOWANCES,
T.FEDERAL_MAR_STATUS,
T.STATE_TAX_CD,
T.SUI_TAX_CD
from 
PS_AUDIT_JOB A
left outer join PS_AL_TAX_DATA T on A.PAYGROUP = T.PAYGROUP and A.FILE_NBR = T.FILE_NBR,
PS_AUDIT_TRANS AT,
PS_PERSONAL_DATA P,
PS_JOB J,
PS_EMPLOYMENT E,
TABLE(DBADM.SECURITYPKG.SEC_MJ_EMPL_F(NULL,'AAA_job_keys6')) B
where A.AUDIT_ACTN = 'A'
and A.ACTION = 'HIR'
and AT.TRANS_SOURCE = '1'
and A.AUDIT_STAMP >= to_date(@SingleQuote.Local.FROMDATE~,'MM/DD/YYYY')
and A.AUDIT_STAMP < to_date(@SingleQuote.Local.THRUDATE~,'MM/DD/YYYY') + 1
and A.AUDIT_OPRID = AT.AUDIT_TRANS_ID
and A.EMPLID = P.EMPLID
and A.EMPLID = J.EMPLID
and A.EMPLID = E.EMPLID
and A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
and A.EMPL_RCD_NBR = J.EMPL_RCD_NBR
and A.EMPL_RCD_NBR = E.EMPL_RCD_NBR
and A.EMPL_RCD_NBR = B.EMPL_RCD_NBR
and A.EFFDT = J.EFFDT
and A.EFFDT = B.EFFDT
and A.EFFSEQ = J.EFFSEQ
and A.EFFSEQ = B.EFFSEQ
and T.EFFDT = (select max(EFFDT)
               from PS_AL_TAX_DATA
               where PAYGROUP = A.PAYGROUP
               and FILE_NBR = A.FILE_NBR
               and EFFDT <= to_date(@SingleQuote.Local.THRUDATE~,'MM/DD/YYYY'))
order by A.EMPLID, A.EFFDT desc, A.EFFSEQ desc
```

When executing it, it displays the following error:

```
org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Cannot get the result set metadata.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
```

SQL error #1:ORA-00911: invalid character

;
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

```
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.newException(ExceptionHandler.java:52)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.throwException(ExceptionHandler.java:108)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.throwException(ExceptionHandler.java:84)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.getRuntimeMetaData(PreparedStatement.java:414)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.getProjectedColumns(PreparedStatement.java:377)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.doGetMetaData(PreparedStatement.java:347)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:563)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.execute(DataSourceQuery.java:980)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery$OdaDSQueryExecutor.executeOdiQuery(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:607)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:1251)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ServiceForQueryResults.executeQuery(ServiceForQueryResults.java:233)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultIterator(QueryResults.java:178)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultMetaData(QueryResults.java:132)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataSetMetaDataHelper.getRuntimeMetaData(DataSetMetaDataHelper.java:196)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataSetMetaDataHelper.getRealMetaData(DataSetMetaDataHelper.java:155)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataSetMetaDataHelper.getDataSetMetaData(DataSetMetaDataHelper.java:117)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataSetMetaDataHelper.refreshMetaData(DataSetMetaDataHelper.java:385)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.refreshMetaData(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:414)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.ExternalUIUtil.updateColumnCache(ExternalUIUtil.java:109)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.providers.DefaultDataServiceProvider.updateColumnCache(DefaultDataServiceProvider.java:139)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.data.DataService.updateColumnCache(DataService.java:173)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetUIUtil.updateColumnCache(DataSetUIUtil.java:99)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetEditor.okPressed(DataSetEditor.java:687)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.property.AbstractPropertyDialog.buttonPressed(AbstractPropertyDialog.java:650)

at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:618)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)

at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)

at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.dialogs.BaseDialog.open(BaseDialog.java:117)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.providers.EditableDataSetNodeProvider.performEdit(EditableDataSetNodeProvider.java:102)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.views.DefaultNodeProvider.performRequest(DefaultNodeProvider.java:472)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.views.actions.EditAction.doAction(EditAction.java:85)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.views.actions.AbstractElementAction.run(AbstractElementAction.java:70)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.views.RenameListener.doubleClick(RenameListener.java:214)

at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:833)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)

at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)

at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)

at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:830)

at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1470)

at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1264)

at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:252)

at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:249)

at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:311)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)

at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)

at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)

at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)

at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)

at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)

at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)

at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)

at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)

at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)

at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)

at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)

at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
SQL error #1:ORA-00911: invalid character

;
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

```
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:482)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.getMetaUsingDefaultPolicy(Statement.java:389)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.getMetaData(Statement.java:330)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.bidi.BidiStatement.getMetaData(BidiStatement.java:56)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.doGetMetaData(OdaQuery.java:423)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.getMetaData(OdaQuery.java:390)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.getRuntimeMetaData(PreparedStatement.java:407)

... 71 more
```

Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query contains "@SingleQuote.Local.THRUDATE~" several times.
Probably what you want to do is to use a parameter.

But the syntax is invalid (try to run your query in SQL*Developer).

The syntax for query parameters (bind variables) is either ? or :p_name.

? is the usual JDBC syntax, :p_name is Oracle-specific, I think.

BIRT supports both versions.

But if you are using the :p_name syntax, be aware that BIRT internally converts each ":xxxxx" into a "?".

Thus, each bind variable must appear exactly once in the query, and the position in the query must match the order of the parameter definitions.

A usual trick to achieve this is the WITH syntax:

```
with params as (
  select :p_deptno      as deptno
       , :p_ename_like  as ename_like
  from DUAL
)
select *
from emp, params
where (params.deptno is null or emp.deptno = params.deptno)
and emp.ename like nvl(:p_ename_like, '%')
```

In this case, you'd need two dataset parameters,
where the first is a deptno, and the second is a pattern for ename.